# UIWebView email hyperlink is not working on device

Tags: html, iphone, ios, uiwebview, html-email

I am displaying a HTML page in my iPhone app. The HTML page has few Email addresses. In Mac desktop browser, if the same HTML page is opened and if i click on email address, MAC machines mailbox is opened to compose a new email. Whereas in iPhone, on clicking the email address it is trying to load the webView thinking it as a link.

How come it is working on MAC browser and not in iPhone app.

Source in HTML is :

```
<a href="mailto:customerinfo@mycompany.com">customerinfo@mycompany.com</a>
```

If i try to handle using MFMailControlViewController, it works. But my real question is, how come MAC desktop launching mail box and iPhone doesn't.

Thanks
Jithen

Answer (score 4):

Go to interface builder to Web View settings. You need to enable Addresses and Links detection.

[image: Setting webView in interface builder]

or

in the code:

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

Comment: I am not maintaining XIB file for this. Just creating new view controller, pushing into navigation controller and loading the webView HTML page..

Comment: I already tried with webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll; but it is not working. My real question is, without doing anything how it is launching mail box in Mac desktop and not in iPhone.